# How to set volume for text-to-speech "speak" method?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-audiomanager

I'm at a lost. I want to be able to adjust the speak volume. Whatever I do, I can't increase its volume. How do I make it as loud as that found in the Android settings (as below)?

System Settings -> Voice input and output -> Text-to-Speech settings -> Listen to an example

My code at this moment is:

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
int loudmax = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,loudmax, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
mTts.speak(name,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` when calling the `setStreamVolume(...)` method. The example speech is affected by the media volume if I adjust the volume of music playback on my phone so I guess `STREAM_MUSIC` is what you need.

**EDIT:** This code works perfectly for me...

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int amStreamMusicMaxVol = am.getStreamMaxVolume(am.STREAM_MUSIC);
am.setStreamVolume(am.STREAM_MUSIC, amStreamMusicMaxVol, 0);
tts.speak("Hello", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

The max volume for `STREAM_MUSIC` on my phone is 15 and I've even tested this by replacing `amStreamMusicMaxVol` in my call to `am.setStreamVolume(...)` above with the values 3, 6, 9, 12, 15 and the volume of the speech is correctly set.

Comment: "Speak" method isn't affected by AudioManager.Stream_MUSIC

Comment: @mmmmm5: ""Speak" method isn't affected by AudioManager.Stream_MUSIC" Yes it is - at least on my HTC Desire. You must be doing something wrong or it just isn't supported on your device/emulator or you need to use `STREAM_SYSTEM` as slayton suggests. See the code I've added in my edit - it works perfectly and I can set the speech volume anywhere between 0-15.

Comment: Thanks. It works. 2 things were preventing me from thinking it wasn't - (1) comparing DMTF tone to speak. DMTF tone is much louder. (2) i was running some other activity which cut off the speak from completing, so it sounded softer

Comment: I found a way to make the speak volume very loud and that can be controlled by the device volume buttons. Use setVolumeControlStream(int streamType)

Comment: But how can i disable all sounds so that even other application can't change any volume. i mean how to completely disable AudioManager from other application. @Squonk

Comment: Documentation link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are changing the volume of notifications. Is the volume of TTS played at the same volume level as notifications? I suspect it isn't and it probably played at either `STREAM_SYSTEM` or `STREAM_MUSIC` Try changing the stream type to one of these:

```
STREAM_VOICE_CALL, STREAM_SYSTEM, STREAM_RING, STREAM_MUSIC or STREAM_ALARM
```

Comment: I was trying to use AudioManager methods (setStreamVolume, getStreamMaxVolume) to make "speak" method louder. But, the "speak" method isn't affected by AudioManager