# Android TextToSpeech Rate, Sound speaker

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have made an app using [TextToSpeech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) Class.. But the voice rate is too slow .. How to increase the rate of Voice..

Secondly the voice comes from the main(small) speaker.. I want that the Sound Should come from
the back speaker(LoudSpeaker).

Answer (score 10):

1) Use function [setSpeechRate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setSpeechRate%28float%29) to make voice faster

> Speech rate. 1.0 is the normal speech rate, lower values slow down the speech (0.5 is half the normal speech rate), greater values accelerate it (2.0 is twice the normal speech rate).

2) Use function [setSpeakerphoneOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn%28boolean%29) to turn On rear Speakerphone.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear, if you want to increase the volume of the voice : you can use the method `setStreamVolume()` on your `AudioManager` (example : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558650/how-to-set-volume-for-text-to-speech-speak-method))
If you want to have a faster voice, try to use this method `setSpeechRate()` or your `TextToSpeech` class. (more information : [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setSpeechRate%28float%29))
About your last question, did you try to change the method `setSpeakerPhoneOn()` in order the speaker? ([AudioManager setSpeakerPhoneOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn%28boolean%29))